# Netmiko - Windows 10 - SSH Router - Not able to run 1st command only

Tags: ssh, router, cisco, netmiko

```
>>> from netmiko import ConnectHandler

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\netmiko\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
```

Hello Experts,

Post applying  from netmiko import ConnectHandler command I am getting above error.

Setup - Windows 10, Python 3.7, Netmiko installed. no other file present in pc with name netmiko.py.

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Netmiko, you need to be in the same python environment that you installed netmiko.

I see you installed Windows 10 and Python 3.7, but the python that is being used to call Netmiko is 2.7. You can tell from the "Python27" in the directory name `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\netmiko\__init__.py`.

Run a Python 3.7 shell and try the command again. Make sure Netmiko is properly installed in the environment.

To verify if netmiko is installed, type `help("modules")` to retrieve a list of all installed packages. If Netmiko was properly installed, you should see it there.

```
Python 3.7.5 (tags/v3.7.5:5c02a39a0b, Oct 15 2019, 00:11:34) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help("modules")

Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

                      ---- output omitted ----

Cryptodome          bdb                 gc                  pyexpat
__future__          binascii            genericpath         pygments
_string             codecs              netaddr             tabnanny
_strptime           codeop              netapp              tarfile
_struct             collections         netmiko             telnetlib
_symtable           colorama            netmiko_globals     tempfile
_testbuffer         colorsys            netrc               terminal_server
_testcapi           compileall          nntplib             test
_testconsole        concurrent          nt                  textfsm
_testimportmultiple configparser        ntpath              textwrap
_testmultiphase     contextlib          nturl2path          this
_textfsm            contextvars         numbers             threading
```

I hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Run : `python3` to access python version 3.5+ terminal.

```
>>>from netmiko import ConnectHandler
```